# In sysvinit, do `telinit` and `init` run in the same process?

Tags: systemd, init, sysvinit

In https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sysvinit-core/init.8.en.html

> **/sbin/telinit is linked to /sbin/init**. It takes a one-character argument and **signals** init to perform the appropriate action.
>
> ...
>
> Init listens on **a fifo in /run, /run/initctl**, for messages. **Telinit uses this to communicate with init.**

Does the first sentence mean that  `telinit` is a symlink to `init`? If yes, is it correct that `telinit` and `init` are run in the same process (e.g. maybe by some file lock) ?  If yes, how can `telinit` communicate with `init` using FIFO or signals?

For comparison, in Systemd, `systemd` and `systemctl` are different program files.  Does  `telinit` perform the same role to `init` in sysvinit, as `systemctl` to `systemd`?

Thanks.

Comment: Uh...Why would you think of that? You can run two chrome process but they both use `chrome.exe`.

Comment: daemon is usually running as a singleton process (I don't know any that isn't), and an init process is a daemon.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand "singleton process", did you mean executables that was designed to run only one process on the system? Daemons might be "singleton process"... or not. Back to your question, you have two process using the same `/sbin/init`, with different logic, of course. I just feel you misunderstand so many basic OS concepts, based on the questions you've asked on this website, yes, I AM WATCHING YOU, because your  questions interested me.

Comment: Uh.. in the bad old time, some server might fork one process per TCP-connection, well, at least that's theoratically possible, right? Also, I wanna tell you, "daemons" are really not well-defined in Linux world, because linux, the kernel, don't care about this concept, only service manager cares about that, but might in different ways from human's mind.

Comment: Does telinit perform the same role to init in sysvinit, as systemctl to systemd?

Comment: Yes, roughly equivalent system management functionality.

Comment: `telinit q` is similar to `systemctl daemon-reload` ; `telinit _runlevel_` is similar to `systemctl isolate ...`

Comment: @神秘德里克 Is `telinit` run as a daemon? If not as a daemon, I think it should be run as a separate process from the `init` process.  I guess `telinit` shouldn't get run as a daemon because `init` is already run as a daemon, unless `telinit` wants to be run as a daemon that performs different work from `init` daemon. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489896/is-telinit-run-as-a-daemon

Comment: Shouldn't I already answered that in the first place? Daemon is NOT a well-defined concept. Usually we don't think telinit as a daemon process. `telinit` is degisned to run as a short-lifetime process which comminicate with init process then exit. Two processes CAN share the same ELF, that's VERY common, even on other systems, sharing ELF doesn't mean anything. All those are already been answered in comments or answers. Even if you're so nit-picking about they share ELF by symbolic link(which actually doesn't matter at all), that question already has an answer about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a symlink, but programs can look at how they are called and perform different actions.  This is extremely common in the Unix world.

And so when you run the `telinit` comamnd, it runs in its own process space, *separate* from the `init` process.  It sends a messgae to the `init` process.  This may be sent via a FIFO, or by a signal, depending on compile time options.