# Is telinit run as a daemon?

Tags: systemd, daemon, init, sysvinit

In sysvinit, [`telinit` is a symlink to `init`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/489804/674).

`init` is run as a daemon. Is `telinit` run as a daemon?

I don't have sysvinit installed on my Lubuntu. For comparison,   `systemctl` plays similar role to `systemd` as `telinit` to `init`,  and `systemctl` has a controlling terminal so is not running as a daemon, while `systemd` is run as a daemon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether a file is a symlink to another one has no bearing on how it runs. `telinit`, like `systemctl`, runs as a “normal” process.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this question and on [In sysvinit, do `telinit` and `init` run in the same process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489804/) I think you're confused around how programs can interact with symlinks.

When a program has multiple names (symlinks, hardlinks) it can do different things based on how it is called.

For example, here's a simple shell script

$ cat x

```
#!/bin/bash

pname=${0##*/}

case $pname in
   tina) echo "Tina Tuner doesn't need another hero" ;;
   fred) echo "The current date is: $(date)" ;;
  harry) sleep 3 ;;
      *) echo Call me tina or fred or harry
esac
```

It has symlinks:

```
$ ls -l x tina fred harry
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sweh sweh   1 Dec 19 09:47 fred -> x*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sweh sweh   1 Dec 19 09:48 harry -> x*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sweh sweh   1 Dec 19 09:48 tina -> x*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sweh sweh 217 Dec 19 09:48 x*
```

So now I can get different results, depending on how I call it:

```
$ ./tina
Tina Tuner doesn't need another hero
$ ./fred
The current date is: Wed Dec 19 09:50:00 EST 2018
$ ./harry
$ ./x
Call me tina or fred or harry
$ ln -s x something
$ ./something
Call me tina or fred or harry
```

Now the `sysv-init` program does something similar.  If started as `telinit` then it simply signals the main `init` program.  If started as `init` (and possibly also if the PID is 1, but that's getting deeper into the weeds) then it starts as the main system init process.

So, no; `telinit` is *not* a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

> init is run as a daemon. Is telinit run as a daemon?

No, init binary has a different behaviour when invoked as telinit.